# Can you use Count(*) in an inner join?

Tags: mysql

Currently I have the following database:

**Table 1: Customer_Stores**

```
unique_id
page_address
date_added
guide_summary
user_name
cover_photo
guide_title
```

**Table 2: Customer_Stories_Likes**

```
story_id
likex
```

The 'like' column in the second table contains a 1 or a 0 to indict whether or not a user has liked a post.

What I'd like to do is join these two tables together with '`post_id`' and count all of the 'likes' for all the posts based on `post_id` and order these by how many likes each post got. Is this possible with a single statement? or is it better to use a `Count(*)` to first determine how many likes each post has?

Comment: If there's no other information in Table 1 you need for this query, then why are you joining at all?

Comment: Updated the OP, sorry about that, didn't have the database to hand at the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you don't need an inner join, because you don't actually need the posts table to do it.

```
SELECT post_id, count(like) AS post_likes
FROM likes
WHERE like = 1
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY post_likes DESC
```

If you need other information from the posts table as well, you could join it to a subquery that gets the like counts.

```
SELECT posts.*, like_count
FROM
posts LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT post_id, count(like) AS like_count
    FROM likes
    WHERE like = 1
    GROUP BY post_id) AS post_likes
ON posts.post_id = post_likes.post_id
ORDER BY like_count DESC
```

I used `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`, you can use `INNER JOIN` if you don't want to include posts with no likes.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @Don't Panic, I have updated the OP to better reflect what data is in the database. I am currently getting an unknown column error error with this: `SELECT customer_stories.*, like_count
FROM customer_stories 
INNER JOIN (SELECT story_id, count(likex) AS like_count FROM customer_stories_likes WHERE likex = 1 GROUP BY unique_id) AS post_likes
ON customer_stories.unique_id = customer_stories_likes.story_id
ORDER BY like_count DESC LIMIT 5`

Comment: @Aaranihlus Looks like the unknown column is "unique_id"  in the subquery. It should be story_id.